# Vue - Which is better? Extend a component or nested component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a drop-down.vue component like this:

```
<template>
    <div @mouseenter="handleEnter" @mouseleave="handleLeave" @click="handleClick" v-click-outside="hide">
        <slot name="dropdownBtn"  :visible="visible" ></slot>
        <slot v-if="visible" name="dropdownWrap"  :visible="visible"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
...
```

it's a drop down component, then click or hover the dropdownBtn the dropdownWrap will apear/disapear.

now i have another component need the dropdown, so i can use the dropdown in two way:

first： use nested component

```
    <template>
        <ui-dropdown>
            <div name="dropdownBtn">...</div>
            <div name="dropdownWrap">...</div>
        </ui-dropdown>
    </template>
...
```

second: use extend

```
<template>
<!-- the handleEnter and handleLeave are extend from the dropdown component -->

<div>
    <div class="btn" @mouseenter="handleEnter" @mouseleave="handleLeave">...</div>
    <div class="popup" @mouseenter="handleEnter" @mouseleave="handleLeave">...</div>
</div>
<template>

<script>
import dropdown from '../dropdown';
export default {
    extend: dropdown,
    ...
}
</script>
```

i think the first is better. but the second has one less component than the first, the performance will be better?

who can tell me which is better?

Answer (score 6):

Both ways work, and I can't really say that one way is correct and the other isn't, it depends on your requirements.

**Extend**

- Extending a base component can get hairy if you want to modify the base component's template in some way (you can't really modify part of the base component's template, you either keep the base template or completely redefine it).
- You need to make sure that the new template adheres to any requirements that the base component needs for it to work correctly (such as the presence of certain `ref`s, using correct CSS class names, etc.
- The base and extended components are tightly coupled.

**Composition**

- I'd say this is more the "Vue way".
- You can take advantage of slots.
- There's no tight coupling between the child and parent components; they're completely separate. You can modify the child component's code as much as you like as long as its interface (props, events, slots, etc) are unchanged.
- A disadvantage could be that the parent component is a completely separate component from the child; it won't inherit any props, events, slots (anything) from the child component.

You might want to have a look at [functional components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) if you're concerned about the overhead of having an extra component with the composition approach.

I rarely extend components, but when I do, it's because I want to share a common blueprint for a set of related components (the base component isn't usually functional on its own, I've just extracted the common code out).